# iOS Hello World over socket

Tags: ios, sockets

I need to implement simple socket communication (strings) between iOS app and my Java socket server. I manage to connect the two, but I cannot send any messages. Java server is pretty much taken from this [example](http://zerioh.tripod.com/ressources/sockets.html), and this is part of my code where I establish connection and (try to) send message to server:

```
- (void)initNetworkCommunication {
CFReadStreamRef readStream;
CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)@"192.168.0.10", 2004, &readStream, &writeStream);
self.inputStream = objc_unretainedObject(readStream);
self.outputStream = objc_unretainedObject(writeStream);
[self.inputStream setDelegate:self];
[self.outputStream setDelegate:self];
[self.inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[self.outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[self.inputStream open];
[self.outputStream open];
}

- (void)sendMessage {
NSString *response  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"aaa"];
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[response dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
[self.outputStream write:[data bytes] maxLength:[data length]];
}

- (void)stream:(NSStream *)theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent {

NSLog(@"stream event %i", streamEvent);

switch (streamEvent) {

    case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted:
        NSLog(@"Stream opened");
        break;
    case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:

        if (theStream == self.inputStream) {

            uint8_t buffer[1024];
            int len;

            while ([self.inputStream hasBytesAvailable]) {
                len = [self.inputStream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)];
                if (len > 0) {

                    NSString *output = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:len encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

                    if (nil != output) {

                        NSLog(@"server said: %@", output);
                        //[self messageReceived:output];

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        break;


    case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred:

        NSLog(@"Can not connect to the host!");
        break;

    case NSStreamEventEndEncountered:

        [theStream close];
        [theStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        theStream = nil;

        break;
    default:
        NSLog(@"Unknown event");
}

}
- (IBAction)loginButtonClicked {
[self initNetworkCommunication];
[self sendMessage];
...}
```

Comment: Hell World is right!  Have you seen the weather?

Comment: Ok, now we can proceed to more useful answers... :-o

Comment: @ClarkKent his was not an answer :)

Comment: @ClarkKent aren't you supposed to be out saving the world?

Comment: I am, but trying to do it over socket so I don't have to get out of my bad...

Comment: I would really appreciate a good answer...

Comment: Did you get a way out of it I am getting this : server said: :{"type":"usermsg","name":null,"message":null,"color":null}

Answer (score 5):

Too late for a reply.. 
Hope this helps someone...

To send a String over Sockets, you must mark the end of the string. ie; Add a \n

For the above example :

Method : ***sendMessage***

```
NSString *response  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"aaa\n"];
```

Comment: Thanx mate i was facing same problem... adding `\n` at the end of string worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Better to add something that can't be typed - e.g., 0x00 - at the end.  That way your message can contain anything.